# How to identify Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I’m trying to define a function that accepts a file pointer of a file that’s already been opened and a pointer to a structure of type String which I have defined as such:

```
typedef struct string {
  char* char_arr;
  int capacity;
  int size;
} String;
```

This should return 1 if the function was able to read from the file and place the first word into the String, and 0 if not. When I ran it however, I receive a “segmentation fault” message. I read that this involved the misuse of a pointer, but I am having trouble finding where that occurred.

```
int string_extraction(FILE* pFile, String* pString){
  char* c_string;
  int i;
  char c;

  fscanf(pFile, " %c", &c);

  for(i=0; !isspace(c) && c != EOF; i++){
  c_string[i] = c;
  c = fgetc(pFile);
  }
  ungetc(c, pFile);

  pString = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
  if (pString != NULL) {
    pString->size = i;
    pString->capacity = i+1;
    pString->char_arr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (pString->capacity));        
    if (pString->char_arr == NULL) {
      free(pString);
      pString = NULL;
    } else pString->char_arr = c_string;
  }

  if(pString == NULL)
    return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You might want to read this: http://c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html -- Google the stdio functions you use and look at their signatures, make sure you pass the correct type parameter and check the return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you asked for 'how to identify' the segfault and not the bug within your code here some words about that topic...

you may run your program in a debugger that is able to catch that kind of error and guide you to the right spot in the code. if you use an environment that offers you GNU tools, you may go using **gcc** and **gdb**.

to be able to get the most out of gdb you need to recompile your program to add debugging symbols:

```
gcc -g your-awesome-program.c -o your-awesome-program
```

you can read about gdb debug flags [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).

no run your program within gdb:

```
gdb your-awesome-program
```

type r (+enter) to run the application and you will get some output like the one below:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /some/where/over/the/rainbow/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400775 in string_extraction (pFile=0x601010, pString=0x7fffffffe310) at ex.c:31
31      c_string[i] = c;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400775 in string_extraction (pFile=0x601010, pString=0x7fffffffe310) at ex.c:31
#1  0x000000000040072a in main () at ex.c:18
(gdb)
```

The line       **c_string[i] = c;** tells you, where the segfault occurred. The command *bt* shows you the call-stack so you can follow the flow of your application till it was killed by a bad accident.

You can read more about gdb [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

Learning how to debug using a debugger like gdb will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

> char* c_string;

Segfault because your `c_string` pointer is uninitialized.

Either use `char []` or `malloc` your pointer before using it in the loop.

```
for(i=0; !isspace(c) && c != EOF; i++){
    c_string[i] = c;   // <-- segfault as c_string not initialized
    ...
}
```